# Add matching string items to dictionary from Querystring

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

Add matching items to dictionary  from Querystring

myQuery = `"RecordFiles/findrecords/$filter=userid eq 8w4W4E and recordid eq 1catf2deb-4wdx-450c-97cd-6rre331d4a6ec";`

string myRegexQueryPattern = `@"^(RecordFiles/findrecords/\$filter=userid eq)\s(?<userid>\S+)((\s(and recordid eq)\s(?<recordid>\w+))|())";`

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dataDictionary;
            Regex myregx = new Regex(myRegexQueryPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            bool status= AddToDictionary(myQuery, myregx, out dataDictionary);
```

But when i run this code I am getting only first part of recordid and is skiping remaining.

**Actual result**

> recordid=1catf2deb

**Expected result**
Here my dictionary should contain

> recordid =1catf2deb-4wdx-450c-97cd-6rre331d4a6ec

Can some one help me get the expected result?Which part of my code is wrong and how can I correct my code to get expected result

```
 public static bool AddToDictionary(string query, Regex regex, out Dictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(query);
            bool status = false;
            string[] groupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();
            data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (match.Success)
            {
                foreach (var groupName in groupNames)
                {
                    data.Add(groupName, match.Groups[groupName].Value);
                }
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of your regexp

```
(?<recordid>\w+)
```

You use the "\w" which matches all word characters, which the character "-" is not a part of.

If you edit it to be

```
(?<recordid>\S+)
or even
(?<recordid>[\w-]+) if you can only allow \w or -
```

You will be able to capture the value that you want, I believe.

In the future, for Regexp testing I would recommend using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It is available for desktop as well as being an online application that visually tells you when your RegEx does/does not pass.